# Convert json file to csv in C# using ChoETL library

Tags: c#, arrays, json, choetl

I am trying to convert a list of objects from a JSON file to excel using this library https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1193650/Cinchoo-ETL-Quick-Start-Converting-JSON-to-CSV-Fil in C#. The object is a JSON array so that means it contains also other objects but some of the objects contain just an empty array (see sensors).

Sensors example object :

```
{
    "id": 4394,
    "uuid": "50124928-f58b-4aa9-ab5b-14ce05058dd1",
    "name": "smarty",
    "description": null,
    "state": "not_configured",
    "system_tags": [
        "indoor",
        "offline"
    ],
    "user_tags": [],
    "last_reading_at": null,
    "added_at": "2017-09-24T13:09:02Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-09-24T13:09:02Z",
    "mac_address": "[FILTERED]",
    "owner": {
        "id": 5424,
        "uuid": "fea238d0-4c8f-4f0c-8ff5-412eca90bf45",
        "username": "smarty",
        "avatar": "https://smartcitizen.s3.amazonaws.com/avatars/default.svg",
        "url": null,
        "joined_at": "2016-07-04T22:23:04Z",
        "location": {
            "city": null,
            "country": null,
            "country_code": null
        },
        "device_ids": []
    },
    "data": {
        "recorded_at": null,
        "added_at": null,
        "location": {
            "ip": null,
            "exposure": "indoor",
            "elevation": null,
            "latitude": 50.1234885,
            "longitude": 8.6892953,
            "geohash": "u0yjjsxq7r",
            "city": "Frankfurt am Main",
            "country_code": "DE",
            "country": "Germany"
        },
        "sensors": []
    },
    "kit": null
```

Example of an object that contains array objects :

```
{
    "id": 3669,
    "uuid": "82d74e41-d37a-4312-ac0a-6fbb5292091e",
    "name": "Hopper 1",
    "description": "Measuring a conference room",
    "state": "has_published",
    "system_tags": [
        "indoor",
        "offline"
    ],
    "user_tags": [
        "Research"
    ],
    "last_reading_at": "2016-11-16T08:52:45Z",
    "added_at": "2016-08-22T10:35:03Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-03-05T19:04:42Z",
    "mac_address": "[FILTERED]",
    "owner": {
        "id": 1756,
        "uuid": "bcf9527f-e159-44c6-a2dd-f646d06520fd",
        "username": "Lassevestergaard",
        "avatar": "https://smartcitizen.s3.amazonaws.com/avatars/default.svg",
        "url": "alexandra.dk",
        "joined_at": "2014-06-30T06:56:33Z",
        "location": {
            "city": "Aarhus N",
            "country": "Denmark",
            "country_code": "DK"
        },
        "device_ids": [
            3669,
            3670
        ]
    },
    "data": {
        "recorded_at": "2016-11-16T08:52:45Z",
        "added_at": "2016-11-16T08:52:45Z",
        "location": {
            "ip": null,
            "exposure": "indoor",
            "elevation": null,
            "latitude": 56.1720539,
            "longitude": 10.1892761,
            "geohash": "u1zpxcg9gm",
            "city": "Aarhus",
            "country_code": "DK",
            "country": "Denmark"
        },
        "sensors": [
            {
                "id": 14,
                "ancestry": null,
                "name": "BH1730FVC",
                "description": "Digital Ambient Light Sensor",
                "unit": "Lux",
                "created_at": "2015-02-02T18:24:56Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-07-05T19:57:36Z",
                "measurement_id": 3,
                "uuid": "ac4234cf-d2b7-4cfa-8765-9f4477e2de5f",
                "value": 1277.6,
                "raw_value": 1277.6,
                "prev_value": 1277.6,
                "prev_raw_value": 1277.6
            },
            {
                "id": 17,
                "ancestry": null,
                "name": "Battery",
                "description": "Custom Circuit",
                "unit": "%",
                "created_at": "2015-02-02T18:26:28Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-07-05T19:55:34Z",
                "measurement_id": 7,
                "uuid": "5b0e390e-781d-4243-8e97-579eead09792",
                "value": 100,
                "raw_value": 100,
                "prev_value": 100,
                "prev_raw_value": 100
            },
            {
                "id": 13,
                "ancestry": "19",
                "name": "HPP828E031",
                "description": "Humidity",
                "unit": "%",
                "created_at": "2015-02-02T18:24:30Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-07-05T19:54:54Z",
                "measurement_id": 2,
                "uuid": "1c19ae8f-b995-460f-87a3-a9d0c140abfb",
                "value": 45.4674072265625,
                "raw_value": 20168,
                "prev_value": 45.4674072265625,
                "prev_raw_value": 20168
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "ancestry": "19",
                "name": "HPP828E031",
                "description": "Temperature",
                "unit": "ºC",
                "created_at": "2015-02-02T18:24:02Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-07-05T19:55:07Z",
                "measurement_id": 1,
                "uuid": "2922d20e-3b83-4d98-8791-cfcdfc12fa99",
                "value": 15.8444018554687,
                "raw_value": 25676,
                "prev_value": 15.8444018554687,
                "prev_raw_value": 25676
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "ancestry": "20",
                "name": "MiCS-4514",
                "description": "NO2",
                "unit": "kOhm/ppm",
                "created_at": "2015-02-02T18:25:51Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-07-05T19:57:59Z",
                "measurement_id": 6,
                "uuid": "0c5b7e74-ef87-431d-89af-dd51de84b10e",
                "value": 244.822,
                "raw_value": 244.822,
                "prev_value": 244.822,
                "prev_raw_value": 244.822
            },
            {
                "id": 16,
                "ancestry": "20",
                "name": "MiCS-4514",
                "description": "CO",
                "unit": "kOhm/ppm",
                "created_at": "2015-02-02T18:26:11Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-07-05T19:58:18Z",
                "measurement_id": 5,
                "uuid": "49a26be4-3ce1-4f2e-a09b-4296fefcfe17",
                "value": 143.169,
                "raw_value": 143.169,
                "prev_value": 143.169,
                "prev_raw_value": 143.169
            },
            {
                "id": 21,
                "ancestry": null,
                "name": "Microchip RN-131",
                "description": "802.11 b/g WiFi",
                "unit": "# networks",
                "created_at": "2015-05-04T11:17:18Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-07-05T19:57:22Z",
                "measurement_id": 9,
                "uuid": "5b1f0e38-336a-4abf-9989-69b48f0026ef",
                "value": 11,
                "raw_value": 11,
                "prev_value": 11,
                "prev_raw_value": 11
            }
```

As you can see one object contain an empty array of sensors and the other and empty one.

This is my code  for the application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ChoETL;

namespace ReadFromJson
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (var csv = new ChoCSVWriter("dev.csv").WithFirstLineHeader())
        {
            using (var json = new ChoJSONReader("device.json"))
            {


                //var result = json.Select(a => a.data.sensors).ToArray();
                csv.Write(json.Select(i => new
                {







                    // Info about device
                    Id = i.id,
                    DeviceUuid = i.uuid,
                    DeviceName = i.name,
                    DeviceDescription = i.description,
                    DeviceState = i.state,
                    UserTags = i.user_tags,
                    LastReading = i.last_reading_at,
                    AddedAt = i.added_at,
                    Updated = i.updated_at,
                    MacAddress = i.mac_address,

                    //Info about owner
                    OwnerID = i.owner.id,
                    OwnerUuid = i.owner.uuid,
                    OwnerUserName = i.owner.username,
                    OwnerAvatar = i.owner.avatar,
                    OwnerUrl = i.owner.url,
                    OwnerJoinDate = i.owner.joined_at,
                    OwnerCity = i.owner.location.city,
                    OwnerCountry = i.owner.location.country,
                    OwnerCountryCode = i.owner.location.country_code,
                    DeviceIds = i.owner.device_ids,

                    //Info about data
                    DataRecorded_At = i.data.recorded_at,
                    DataAdded_At = i.data.added_at,
                    DataLocation = i.data.location.ip,
                    DataExposure = i.data.location.exposure,
                    DataElevation = i.data.location.elevation,
                    DataLatitude = i.data.location.latitude,
                    DataLongitude = i.data.location.longitude,
                    DataGeoLocation = i.data.location.geohash,
                    DataCity = i.data.location.city,
                    DataCountryCode = i.data.location.country_code,
                    DataCountry = i.data.location.country,
                    //SensorBattery
                    SensorsId = i.data.sensors[0].id,
                    SensortAncestry = i.data.sensors[0].ancestry,
                    SensorName = i.data.sensors[0].name,
                    SensorDescription = i.data.sensors[0].description,
                    SensorUnit = i.data.sensors[0].unit,
                    SensorCreatedAt = i.data.sensors[0].created_at,
                    SensorUpdated_at = i.data.sensors[0].updated_at,
                    SensorMeasurement_id = i.data.sensors[0].measurement_id,
                    SensorUuid = i.data.sensors[0].uuid,
                    SensorValue = i.data.sensors[0].value,
                    SensorRawValue = i.data.sensors[0].raw_value,
                    SensorPrevValue = i.data.sensors[0].prev_value,
                    SensorPrevRawValue = i.data.sensors[0].prev_raw_value,

                    //SensorHumidity
                    SensorsHumidityId = i.data.sensors[1].id,
                    SensortHumidityAncestry = i.data.sensors[1].ancestry,
                    SensorHumidityName = i.data.sensors[1].name,
                    SensorHumidityDescription = i.data.sensors[1].description,
                    SensorHumidityUnit = i.data.sensors[1].unit,
                    SensorHumidityCreatedAt = i.data.sensors[1].created_at,
                    SensorumidityUpdated_at = i.data.sensors[1].updated_at,
                    SensorHumidityMeasurement_id = i.data.sensors[1].measurement_id,
                    SensorHumidityUuid = i.data.sensors[1].uuid,
                    SensorHumidityValue = i.data.sensors[1].value,
                    SensorHumidityRawValue = i.data.sensors[1].raw_value,
                    SensorHumidityPrevValue = i.data.sensors[1].prev_value,
                    SensorHumidityPrevRawValue = i.data.sensors[1].prev_raw_value,

                    //Temperature
                    SensorsTemperatureId = i.data.sensors[2].id,
                    SensortTemperatureAncestry = i.data.sensors[2].ancestry,
                    SensorTemperatureName = i.data.sensors[2].name,
                    SensorTemperatureDescription = i.data.sensors[2].description,
                    SensorTemperatureUnit = i.data.sensors[2].unit,
                    SensorTemperatureCreatedAt = i.data.sensors[2].created_at,
                    SensorTemperatureUpdated_at = i.data.sensors[2].updated_at,
                    SensorTemperatureMeasurement_id = i.data.sensors[2].measurement_id,
                    SensorTemperatureyUuid = i.data.sensors[2].uuid,
                    SensorTemperatureValue = i.data.sensors[2].value,
                    SensorTemperatureRawValue = i.data.sensors[2].raw_value,
                    SensorTemperaturePrevValue = i.data.sensors[2].prev_value,
                    SensorTemperaturePrevRawValue = i.data.sensors[2].prev_raw_value,

                    //No2 gas sensor

                    SensorsNo2Id = i.data.sensors[3].id,
                    SensortNo2Ancestry = i.data.sensors[3].ancestry,
                    SensorNo2Name = i.data.sensors[3].name,
                    SensorNo2Description = i.data.sensors[3].description,
                    SensorNo2Unit = i.data.sensors[3].unit,
                    SensorNo2CreatedAt = i.data.sensors[3].created_at,
                    SensorMo2Updated_at = i.data.sensors[3].updated_at,
                    SensorNo2Measurement_id = i.data.sensors[3].measurement_id,
                    SensorNo2Uuid = i.data.sensors[3].uuid,
                    SensorNo2Value = i.data.sensors[3].value,
                    SensorNo2RawValue = i.data.sensors[3].raw_value,
                    SensorNo2PrevValue = i.data.sensors[3].prev_value,
                    SensorNo2PrevRawValue = i.data.sensors[3].prev_raw_value,


                    //CO2 gas sensor 
                    SensorsCo2Id = i.data.sensors[4].id,
                    SensortCo2Ancestry = i.data.sensors[4].ancestry,
                    SensorCo2Name = i.data.sensors[4].name,
                    SensorCo2Description = i.data.sensors[4].description,
                    SensorCo2Unit = i.data.sensors[4].unit,
                    SensorCo2CreatedAt = i.data.sensors[4].created_at,
                    SensorCo2Updated_at = i.data.sensors[4].updated_at,
                    SensorCo2Measurement_id = i.data.sensors[4].measurement_id,
                    SensorCo2Uuid = i.data.sensors[4].uuid,
                    SensorCo2Value = i.data.sensors[4].value,
                    SensorCo2RawValue = i.data.sensors[4].raw_value,
                    SensorCo2PrevValue = i.data.sensors[4].prev_value,
                    SensorCo2PrevRawValue = i.data.sensors[4].prev_raw_value,


                    //Network sensor


                    SensorsNetworkId = i.data.sensors[5].id,
                    SensortNetworkAncestry = i.data.sensors[5].ancestry,
                    SensorNetworkName = i.data.sensors[5].name,
                    SensorNetworkDescription = i.data.sensors[5].description,
                    SensorNetworkUnit = i.data.sensors[5].unit,
                    SensorNetworkCreatedAt = i.data.sensors[5].created_at,
                    SensorNetworkUpdated_at = i.data.sensors[5].updated_at,
                    SensorNetworkMeasurement_id = i.data.sensors[5].measurement_id,
                    SensorNetworkUuid = i.data.sensors[5].uuid,
                    SensorNetworkValue = i.data.sensors[5].value,
                    SensorNetworkRawValue = i.data.sensors[5].raw_value,
                    SensorNetworkPrevValue = i.data.sensors[5].prev_value,
                    SensorNetworkPrevRawValue = i.data.sensors[5]?.prev_raw_value,




                    //decibel sensor  db

                    SensorsDBId = i.data.sensors[6].id,
                    SensorDBAncestry = i.data.sensors[6].ancestry,
                    SensorDBName = i.data.sensors[6].name,
                    SensorDBDescription = i.data.sensors[6].description,
                    SensorDBUnit = i.data.sensors[6].unit,
                    SensorDBCreatedAt = i.data.sensors[6].created_at,
                    SensorDBUpdated_at = i.data.sensors[6].updated_at,
                    SensorDBMeasurement_id = i.data.sensors[6].measurement_id,
                    SensorDBUuid = i.data.sensors[6].uuid,
                    SensorDBValue = i.data.sensors[6].value,
                    SensorDBRawValue = i.data.sensors[6].raw_value,
                    SensorDBPrevValue = i.data.sensors[6].prev_value,
                    SensorDBPrevRawValue = i.data.sensors[6].prev_raw_value,

                    // LDR Analog Light Sensor

                    LightSensorsId = i.data.sensors[7].id,
                    LightSensortAncestry = i.data.sensors[7].ancestry,
                    LightSensorName = i.data.sensors[7].name,
                    LightSensorDescription = i.data.sensors[7].description,
                    LightSensorUnit = i.data.sensors[7].unit,
                    LightSensorCreatedAt = i.data.sensors[7].created_at,
                    LightSensorUpdated_at = i.data.sensors[7].updated_at,
                    LightSensorMeasurement_id = i.data.sensors[7].measurement_id,
                    LightSensorUuid = i.data.sensors[7].uuid,
                    LightSensorValue = i.data.sensors[7].value,
                    LightSensorRawValue = i.data.sensors[7].raw_value,
                    LightSensorPrevValue = i.data.sensors[7].prev_value,
                    LightSensorPrevRawValue = i.data.sensors[7].prev_raw_value,

                    //solar panel 
                    SolarPaneltSensorsId = i.data.sensors[8].id,
                    SolarPanelSensortAncestry = i.data.sensors[8].ancestry,
                    SolarPanelName = i.data.sensors[8].name,
                    SolarPanelSensorDescription = i.data.sensors[8].description,
                    SolarPanelSensorUnit = i.data.sensors[8].unit,
                    SolarPanelSensorCreatedAt = i.data.sensors[8].created_at,
                    SolarPanelSensorUpdated_at = i.data.sensors[8].updated_at,
                    SolarPanelSensorMeasurement_id = i.data.sensors[8].measurement_id,
                    SolarPanelSensorUuid = i.data.sensors[8].uuid,
                    SolarPanelSensorValue = i.data.sensors[8].value,
                    SolarPanelSensorRawValue = i.data.sensors[8].raw_value,
                    SolarPanelSensorPrevValue = i.data.sensors[8].prev_value,
                    SolarPanelSensorPrevRawValue = i.data.sensors[8].prev_raw_value,



                    KitId = i.kit.id,
                    KitUuid = i.kit.uuid,
                    KitSlug = i.kit.slug,
                    KitName = i.kit.name,
                    KitDescription = i.kit.description,
                    KitCreatedAt = i.kit.created_at,
                    KitUpdatedAt = i.kit.updated_at

                }));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

After I tun the program I get this error : 
"System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' "

Does someone know how to read the empty arrays from my list of objects ? or maybe other solution to read and convert to JSON to excel file using C#.

Comment: Are you sure every entry has a value for `i.data.sensors[n]`

Comment: The standard number of sensors are 9 for each device. Some devices do not contain any sensors.

Comment: So what does your code do for  `i.data.sensors[8]` when a device doesn't contain any sensor?

Comment: It's trying to read something that not exists in the array, but my question is how to read in both cases when the array is empty and not empty.

Comment: we generally use `if` to check. You may want to try it

Comment: If your target application is Excel (or most anything else really), why not emit an .xlsx instead of CSV? (The code wouldn't be very different so you'd still have this question.)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues found in your code,

sensors array can be empty, you must check it before accessing its members. Also kit object may be null, you must check for nullability before accessing its members.

Sample shows how to do it.

```
        using (var csv = new ChoCSVWriter("*** OUTPUT CSV FILE PATH ***").WithFirstLineHeader())
        {
            using (var json = new ChoJSONReader("*** INPUT JSON FILE PATH ***"))
            {
                //var result = json.Select(a => a.data.sensors).ToArray();
                csv.Write(json.Select(i => new
                {
                    // Removed code for readability 

                    //SensorBattery

                    SensorsId = i.data.sensors.Length > 0 ? i.data.sensors[0].id : 0,
                    SensortAncestry = i.data.sensors.Length > 0 ? i.data.sensors[0].ancestry : null,
                    SensorName = i.data.sensors.Length > 0 ? i.data.sensors[0].name : null,
                    SensorDescription = i.data.sensors.Length > 0 ? i.data.sensors[0].description : null,
                    SensorUnit = i.data.sensors.Length > 0 ? i.data.sensors[0].unit : 0,
                    SensorCreatedAt = i.data.sensors.Length > 0 ? i.data.sensors[0].created_at : DateTime.MinValue,
                    SensorUpdated_at = i.data.sensors.Length > 0 ? i.data.sensors[0].updated_at : DateTime.MinValue,
                    SensorMeasurement_id = i.data.sensors.Length > 0 ? i.data.sensors[0].measurement_id : 0,
                    SensorUuid = i.data.sensors.Length > 0 ? i.data.sensors[0].uuid : null,
                    SensorValue = i.data.sensors.Length > 0 ? i.data.sensors[0].value : 0,
                    SensorRawValue = i.data.sensors.Length > 0 ? i.data.sensors[0].raw_value : 0,
                    SensorPrevValue = i.data.sensors.Length > 0 ? i.data.sensors[0].prev_value : 0,
                    SensorPrevRawValue = i.data.sensors.Length > 0 ? i.data.sensors[0].prev_raw_value : 0,

                    // Removed code for readability 

                    KitId = i.kit != null ? i.kit.id : null,
                    KitUuid = i.kit != null ? i.kit.uuid : null,
                    KitSlug = i.kit != null ? i.kit.slug : null,
                    KitName = i.kit != null ? i.kit.name : null,
                    KitDescription = i.kit != null ? i.kit.description : null,
                    KitCreatedAt = i.kit != null ? i.kit.created_at : null,
                    KitUpdatedAt = i.kit != null ? i.kit.updated_at : null

                }));

            }
        }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I found something interesting, what if my object in time changes the number of sensors or one propriety is removed? How can that be handled?  How must the object be defined?

Comment: Use ContainsKey(“fieldname”) to check on property existence.

Comment: can you please write an example to see where exactly that must be specified?

Comment: Let’s say you want to check if ‘kit’ is present or not, you can write like i.ContainsKey(“kit”)

Comment: `KitId = i.ContainsKey("kit.id") != null ? i.kit.id : 0` if I added as in example it throws an exception **Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference**. Then I if run it without `!=null` is adding to every column the value _0_.  The same for  `SensorMeasurement_id = i.data.sensors.Length > 0 ? i.data.sensors[0].measurement_id : 0` ` is not working. Maybe I not typing the sintax correctly.